# Using R to access Pheedloop API

Tags: r, json, rcurl

My organization uses Pheedloop and I'm trying to build a dynamic solution for access its data.

So, how do I access the Pheedloop API using R? Specifically, how do I accurately submit my API credentials to Pheedloop and download data. I also need the final data to be in a dataframe format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RCurl` package along with `jsonlite`.  Importantly, you need to send a header with your request.

```
orgcode<-'yourcode'
myapikey<-'yourapikey'
mysecret<-'yourapisecret'
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)

# AUTHENTICATION
authen<-paste0("https://api.pheedloop.com/api/v3/organization/",orgcode,"/validateauth/") # create a link with parameters

RCurl::getURL(
  authen,
  httpheader = c('X-API-KEY' = myapikey, 'X-API-SECRET' = mysecret),    # include key and     secret in the header like this
  verbose = TRUE)


# LIST EVENTS
events<-paste0("https://api.pheedloop.com/api/v3/organization/",orgcode, " events/")

# the result will be a JSON file
cscEvents<-getURL( 
  events,
  httpheader = c('X-API-KEY' = myapikey, 'X-API-SECRET' = mysecret), 
  verbose = FALSE)   

cscEvents<-fromJSON(cscEvents );  # using jsonlite package to parse json format
cscEventsResults<-cscEvents$results  # accessing the results table
table(cscEventsResults$event_name)  # examine
```